# how do i define a constant in a string in PHP?

Tags: php, string, constants

I am using a constant `NEWS_POST_NUMBER` and i am getting confused on how to attach it to a string to query it to database. i tried many things and it is giving errors.

here is the string i tried.

```
$query = "
SELECT news.id, news.timestamp, news.title 
FROM news 
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT $from, NEWS_POST_NUMBER";
```

please note `NEWS_POST_NUMBER` is the constant i have defined i want to attach it to query how do i do it?

Comment: Remember.. php.net is your friend: http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$query = "
SELECT news.id, news.timestamp, news.title 
FROM news 
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT $from, " . NEWS_POST_NUMBER;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$query = "SELECT news.id, news.timestamp, news.title FROM news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $from, " . NEWS_POST_NUMBER;
```

Use the [concatenation operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) ;)